# Finding a matching date and title among many variables in SAS

Tags: sas, match

I have a data set that is a list of employees with their job titles and month and year that job title started for their entire career here.
It looks something like this: employeeID JobTitle1 MonthYearofTitle1 Department1 Jobtitle2 MonthYearofTitle2 Department2 etc.

I have another list of employees that are not in the first data set and only have one job title and date of title. My goal is to match employees in the 2nd data set with employees in the 1st based on their job title and month/year, but I am completely unsure of how to do this match because it involves information being present among multiple variables.

Put another way, if I have MarySue who has became an admin in Jan2017, I want to match her with JohnDoe who also became an admin in Jan2017 and flag them as a match for further analysis.

Unfortunately, I am not sure where to even begin with my code so I don't have things I've tried. The data would look like this

Data set 1

```
employeeID JobTitle1 MonthYearofTitle1 Jobtitle2 MonthYearofTitle2
JohnDoe    Intern    Jan2016           Admin     Jan2017
JakeSo     VP        Jul2017
JulieDo    Manager   April2017
```

Data set 2

```
employeeID JobTitle1 MonthYearofTitle1 
MarySue    Admin     Jan2017
JaneDoe    Admin     Jan2017  
Greg       VP        Jul2017
```

Desired Outcome / Data set:

```
Employee1   Employee2   Title   Date    Flag
JohnDoe     MarySue     Admin   Jan2017 Match
JakeSo      Greg        VP      Jul2017 Match
JulieDo                 Admin   Jan2017 No Match
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: For help you'll need to include more information, for starters, what do you have - show a sample of your data. If it's confidential, make fake data that reflects your real data. And show what you've tried for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `FULL JOIN` or `Left JOIN`and use `Case` statement to create a calculated field to indicate the matching records.

The code below will do a Full Join and create a flag field:

**Creating  Table1 & Table2: Only 1 record will match**

```
data table1;
input employeeID $ JobTitle1 $ MonthYearofTitle1 Jobtitle2 $ MonthYearofTitle2 ;
informat MonthYearofTitle1 monyy7. MonthYearofTitle2 monyy7.;
format MonthYearofTitle1 monyy7. MonthYearofTitle2 monyy7.;
datalines;
JohnDoe Intern Jan2016 Admin Jan2017
TomJones Junior Jul2016 Admin Jul2017
;
run;

data table2;
input employeeID $ JobTitle1 $ MonthYearofTitle1 ;
informat MonthYearofTitle1 monyy7.;
format MonthYearofTitle1 monyy7.;
datalines;
MarySue Admin Jan2017
JackieC Admin Jul2013
;
run;
```

**Full Join: To get all data**

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
t1.employeeID as t1_employeeID , t2.employeeID as t2_employeeID, 
t2.JobTitle1 as t2_JobTitle,
t2.MonthYearofTitle1 as t2_MonthYearofTitle1,
case when 
((t1.JobTitle1=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle1=t2.MonthYearofTitle1) or (t1.JobTitle2=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle2=t2.MonthYearofTitle1)) then "Match"
else "No-Match" end as flag
from table1 as t1 full join table2 as t2
on  (t1.JobTitle1=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle1=t2.MonthYearofTitle1) or (t1.JobTitle2=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle2=t2.MonthYearofTitle1)
;
quit;
```

**Results:**

[image: Full Join]

```
t1_employeeID=JohnDoe t2_employeeID=MarySue t2_JobTitle=Admin t2_MonthYearofTitle1=JAN2017 flag=Match
t1_employeeID=  t2_employeeID=JackieC t2_JobTitle=Admin t2_MonthYearofTitle1=JUL2013 flag=No-Match
t1_employeeID=TomJones t2_employeeID=  t2_JobTitle=  t2_MonthYearofTitle1=. flag=No-Match
```

**Update:**

**Left Join: To get only records from table 1**

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
t1.employeeID as Employee1    , t2.employeeID as Employee2, 
coalescec(t2.JobTitle1,t1.JobTitle2,t1.JobTitle1) as Title,
coalesce(t2.MonthYearofTitle1,t1.MonthYearofTitle2,t1.MonthYearofTitle1) as Date format monyy7.,
case when 
((t1.JobTitle1=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle1=t2.MonthYearofTitle1) or (t1.JobTitle2=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle2=t2.MonthYearofTitle1)) then "Match"
else "No-Match" end as Flag
from table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2
on  (t1.JobTitle1=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle1=t2.MonthYearofTitle1) or (t1.JobTitle2=t2.JobTitle1 and t1.MonthYearofTitle2=t2.MonthYearofTitle1) 
;
quit;
```

[image: Left Join]

Comment: This works for the most part. The only issue I'm currently having is it is using the same employee from the data set multiple times to match instead of an individual match. Do you have any suggestions on how to indicate that it should only use each employeeID once as a match?

Comment: Its a 'FULL JOIN', so it will match all the rows based on the 'On' clause.  You can change it to Left or Right joins but you will then miss non-matching records.

Comment: Please, add an example of the scenario you have in mind

Comment: Edited with the desired outcome!

Comment: Just Change my 'FULL JOIN' to 'LEFT JOIN' to get the desired output above. I've added to my answer the left join and the new names you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.  First change both datasets so the have just the following columns:

```
employeeID, JobTitle, MonthYear
```

then do a proc sql:

```
proc sql noprint:
     select a.employeeID,b.employeeId,a.jobTitle,a.MonthYear
            from firstdataset as a
                 inner join seconddataset as b
                      on a.employeeId = b.employeeId
                       and a.jobTitle = b.jobTitle
                       and a.MonthYear = b.MonthYear;                           
quit;
```

Give that a go and let me know what you get

also, depending on your data you can create the initial tables with:

```
data b;
keep employeeId title monthyear;
set a;
array x [*] _CHARACTER_;
y= dim(x);

do i = 2 to y;
   if (mod(i,2) = 0)then do;
      Title = x[i];
      monthyear = x[i+1];
      output;
   end;
end ;
run;
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe this will work, but I'll give it a try. Each employee has many titles for many different dates and I simply don't know where data set 2's title and date will match any of the title and date columns from data set 1 and so can't just bring it down to those three variables.

Comment: @kelly, I think you are mistaken.  You will have multiple rows for each employeeID that has more than 1 job title.  The code above should work.  If you have sample data I can work with I'll run it through to make sure